# Prove f(n) is always O(f(n-1))

Tags: math, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Assume that f(n) goes to infinity as n goes to infinity.

This is a homework problem and I would appreciate an idea/guidance instead of the complete answer.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that. Neglect the g(n) from the description.

Comment: You could also fix the description.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Comment: To give a fuller answer than below, if `f(n)=O(f(n-1))`, then `log f(n) = O(n)`, and if `log f(n) != O(n)` (for example, `log n! = O(n log n) != O(n)`), then `f(n)!=O(f(n-1))`.

Comment: Guys, don't you regard asymptotic complexity and algorithm analysis as part of Computer Science/programming?!

Comment: Yes, which is why the question may be better served at http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't true.  Consider the function f(n) = n! as a counterexample, which definitely goes toward infinity as n goes to infinity.  We can prove, though, that n! ≠ O((n - 1)!).

The proof is by contradiction.  Suppose that n! = O((n - 1)!).  Then there exists some n<sub>0</sub> and c such that for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>, we have n! ≤ c(n - 1)!.  This means that for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>,  we have that n! / (n - 1)! ≤ c, or that n ≤ c.  But if we pick n = max{n<sub>0</sub>, c} + 1, then we know that n ≥ n<sub>0</sub> and that n ≥ c + 1, contradicting that n ≤ c.  Since we have a contradiction, the assumption must be wrong and therefore n! ≠ O((n - 1)!).

In case you're wondering how I came up with this: my idea was to find a function that grows so rapidly that no matter what constant you picked, the ratio between f(n + 1) and f(n) would eventually get so large that it would exceed that constant.  It just happened to be the case that n! fit the bill.  In retrospect, I should have remembered that n! ≠ O((n - 1)!) because many algorithms have runtimes like O((n + 1)!), which doesn't simplify down to O(n!).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Shouldn't it be n>= c+1 ?

Comment: @ArunKumar- Ah, yes, that's right.  Fixed!